# PDE with boundary condition (differential equation)

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am trying to find a solution to this boundary value problem

$$h_t= \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 x^2 h_{xx} + r x h_x \quad s.t.\\ 
Ah(b,t)+Bh_x(b,t)=g(t),$$
where $A,B,\sigma,r,b$ are constants and $g(t)$ is a given function of time ($h_x$ is the partial derivative w.r.t. the first component of $h(x,t)$).

I need an explicit solution for it, whatever it is (any solutions satisfying the PDE and the boundary condition will be fine). I tried to use these commands, but it did not give anything:

```
eqn = 1/2 x^2 \[Sigma]^2 D[h[x, t], {x, 2}] + r x D[h[x, t], x] - D[h[x, t], {t}] == 0;
ibc = {A h[b, t] + B Derivative[1, 0][h][b, t] == g[t]}; 
sol = DSolveValue[{eqn, ibc}, h[x, t], {x, t}] // FullSimplify
```

I think I need to use something else, but I am just a beginner in Mathematica.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: For one thing, you're being inconsistent in your function h. Sometimes you say h[x,t], and other times you say h[t,x].

Comment: Thank you for that, it was a typo, I re-edited the post. But that still doesn't work. Do you have any idea of the commands I should use for solving this boundary value problem?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that an analytical solution to the PDE actually exists, even without the boundary condition?  If not, you need to solve it numerically using `NDSolve`.  Please provide numerical values for all constants, if you wish help with `NDSolve`.

Comment: Yes, I have. Basically this PDE arises in the Black-Scholes model, and after a change of variable one can reduce it to the heat equation, that has of course a solution. Also, with the boundary condition one can construct semi-explicit solution (up to inversion of transform, like Laplace). My point is that I need a solution of this problem for a part of my work. I tried to find functions h that satisfies the boundary condition and then try to make it solve the PDE as well... Btw thank you for the suggestion, but I need an analytical solution, not numerical unfortunately...

Comment: I now agree that one can construct the Laplace transform of the solution, and this should be feasible using Mathematica. Actually performing the inverse transform for arbitrary g[t] to obtain the explicit solution is another matter.